# Why $\text{im}(\phi) \cong R/I$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

I didn't understand the last sentence of the proof at the bottom of page 1, top of page 2 in [this link](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-703-modern-algebra-spring-2013/lecture-notes/MIT18_703S13_pra_l_18.pdf), and quoted below:

> *Let $R$ be a domain of finite characteristic. Then the characteristic is prime.*
>
> *Proof.* Let $\phi\colon\mathbb{Z}\to R$ be a ring homomorphism. Then $\phi(1)=1$. Note that $\mathbb{Z}$ is a cyclic group under addition. Thus there is a unique map that sends $1$ to $1$ and is a group homomorphism. Thus $\phi$ is certainly unique and it is not hard to check that in fact $\phi$ is a ring homomorphism.
>
> Now suppose that $R$ is an integral domain. Then the image of $\phi$ is an integral domain. In particular, the kernel $I$ of $\phi$ is a prime ideal. Suppose that $I=\langle p\rangle$. Then the image of $\phi$ is isomorphic to $R/I$ and so the characteristic is equal to $p$.

I didn't understand why image of $\phi: \mathbb{Z} \to R$ is isomorphic to $R/I=R/\left\langle p\right\rangle$.

By 1st isomorphism theorem,  we have $\mathbb{Z}/(p) \cong \text{im}(\phi)$.

Any explanation please

Comment: it's a consequence of the first homomorphism theorem

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems#Rings

Comment: Looks like an error. It should be $\mathbb Z/I,$ not $R/I.$ $I$ is not an ideal of $R.$

Comment: @aldodecristo That would make sense if $I$ was an ideal of $R,$ but it is not, it is an ideal of $\mathbb Z.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, yes that is what I am thinking unless $\phi(I)=I$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews,  if   it is error, how does the last sentence of the proof follows?

Comment: yeah it's wrong since you can't quotient $R$ with and ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: There is nothing about $R$ to indicate it is a superset of $\mathbb Z,$ so there’s no way that $\phi(I)=I.$ indeed, $I$ is defined as the kernel if $\phi,$ so so $\phi(I)=\{0\}.$ @Masmath

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, I understand but how then the proof follows ?

Comment: It is, literally, the *First Isomorphism Theorem* for rings. If you don't know about the isomorphism theorems yet, then you should not be reading about domains and characteristics yet.

Comment: Please do not rely on images; they are not searchable, and many screen readers cannot handle them, making your post inaccessible to those who use them. Please typeset sufficient content that your post is not unintelligible without access to the image.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin,  for your information I have attached the link. See [Proof]  link in the very first line of my question.

Comment: Prove if $R$ is a ring, and $S$ is a sub-ring, and $S$ has characteristic $n,$ then $R$ has characteristic $n.$ In this case, $S=\operatorname{im}(\phi),$ which you have show has prime characteristic.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin it is not the first isomorphism. And that comment is rude.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, your first comment was rude. It was an error and hence I couldn't understand but now I got it.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, Thanks. I got it.

Comment: I know you attached the link; that still forces people to go to a site outside this to go download a *4 page document* where there is no way to tell exactly from where you took the image unless you can compare them; that is, unless you can actually see the image. The link does not solve the accessibility issue.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin is correct about accessibility. And images are wrong for other reasons in this community: it breaks the search engines, internal and external, so people seeking answers to the same question might not find this one, leading to duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be an error in the proof.

$I$ is the kernel of $\phi,$ so $I$ is not even an ideal in $R,$ so $R/I$ is meaningless.

The correct statement is that $\operatorname{im}(\phi)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/I,$ which is a result of the first isomorphism theorem.

This shows that $R$ has prime characteristic if you know a simple result:

> If $R$ is a ring, and $S$ is a sub-ring, and $S$ has characteristic $n,$ then $R$ has characteristic $n.$

In your case, $S=\operatorname{im}(\phi),$ which we have shown has  prime characteristic.